# Calling a method at a certain time of a music using getCurrentPositon

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

There is background music in my app and I want to call a method at a certain time of that music,for example when *mymusic.getCurrentPosition()* returns 30000 I want to call that method.How can I achieve this?

Comment: A simple work around will work  by starting a timer at the start of the music play.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? What's `mymusic`?